# URL with without www shows just a blank page

Tags: urls

i have a little problem with my wordpress page...

when I enter the URL with www, the page is shown the right way. But when I enter it without www, then it shows just a blank page and the source code just shows the html, head and body tag...

www.blumengalerie.ch /

Also the page displays this white page when I enter a subpage without the backslash at the end (www.blumengalerie.ch/kontakt/)

I called my hoster and he assured me, the both (www/no www) are assigned to the same path...

I've updated the permalinks and the .htaccess file shows only the entry for the permalinks...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Dows anyone know what the problem could be? I could really use some help

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Most of the time this is failure to point an `A` record properly. Check to make sure the record for `www` is the same as the `A` or `@` record.

Comment: disable plugins and switch to default theme, does it still happen?

Comment: @GhostToast that wouldn't explain the missing trailing slash issue though, it sounds more like something is breaking the canonical url function